# Capture Video and Audio and write it to server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video

I tried to capture video and write it to following url.I am getting this error.

**Code:**

```
videoURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://belterra.webiguide.com/uploadimages/VideoRecord.mpeg4"];

_videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:videoURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                            error:&error];
```

**Exception:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter initWithURL:fileType:error:] 
invalid parameter not satisfying: [outputURL isFileURL]'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation           0x314d0987 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
        1   libobjc.A.dylib          0x319a149d objc_exception_throw + 24
        2   AVFoundation             0x30690421 -[AVAssetWriter initWithURL:fileType:error:] + 188
        3   iChat                    0x00003155 -[AVCaptureVideo setupWriter] + 116
        4   iChat                    0x000030a3 -[AVCaptureVideo startVideoRecording] + 26
        5   iChat                    0x000039ed -[AVCaptureVideo initCapture] + 1112

<snip>

    )
```

Comment: I am not sure but I guess the link is not working http://belterra.webiguide.com/uploadimages/VideoRecord.mpeg4

Answer (score 2):

`invalid parameter not satisfying: [outputURL isFileURL]'`

It looks like it's expecting a local file path but in URL format e.g. `file://....`

from the docs

`Initializes an asset writer for writing to the file identified by a given URL in a format specified by a given UTI.`

You would then have to manage the upload to your webserver separately.